# how to tell which project a .cpp file is in

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I took over a C++ code which is in a solution. That one solution contains many projects. I edit a .cpp file, but can't file which project it belongs to, so I don't know which project to build. Building the whole solution takes a long time. How do I find out which project a .cpp file belongs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think this is kind of the point of `.vcxproj` files.  The projects `<->` files relationship is many-to-many.  That is, a project contains many files, but *also*, a file can belong to many projects (in the same solution).

So I'm not sure if you can do this in an easier way, but you can *right click* the tab of the file you need to know about, and select "**Open containing folder**", see which project folder that file resides in, and assume it belongs to that project.

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried that, but there isn't a project in that directory or one directory above :(

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio, click Edit - Find and Replace - Find in Files

Where it says 'Find what"'
Type in the name of the file you are interested in.

Where it says 'Look in:'
Type in the path where you want to search under or use the [...] browse button

Where it says 'Look at these file types:'
Type in *.vcxproj

It should list all the project files that include that file in the 'Find Results' window.

Answer (score 3):

This does the trick for me in Visual Studio 2010:

Tools > Options,
Projects and Solutions > General,
check "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer"

This will cause the folder containing the file to open up in the solution explorer when the file is active in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

If the project files are built properly, you don't need to worry about which projects to build. If you do `Build/Build Solution` (or the `F7` key) the dependencies will be tracked and Visual Studio will only build the projects that depend on the updated file.

If the entire solution gets rebuilt, that means every project depends on the file you just edited, so naturally they *should* all be built. Unless you did `Build/Rebuild Solution`.

Comment: Unless you don't build most of the projects most of the time, and get new files frequently from your source control.  Then you're hosed.  Like at my job!

Comment: @MooingDuck, time to ask your boss for a faster computer. Unless you like it that way: http://xkcd.com/303/

Comment: Our dedicated build server takes about four hours to build the whole project, and we've got developers in four countries constantly checking in code.  My computer isn't the problem.

Comment: @MooingDuck, Ah I see - you have my condolences. In a project that large it's hard to remove all the interdependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem today and I found this post while searching the Internet for an answer. I couldn't find one anywhere but I did happen to come up with one myself. Just in case anyone else needs this solution, here it is:

This solution requires the Unix utility grep . If you're a windows user without it, look up CygWin and install it. It's a bundle of rather useful Unix programs for windows users. Anyway:

1. In your shell (command prompt, bash, etc) navigate to the where all your project files are. In my case, there was a single folder that held a bunch of folders, each containing a project file. In my case I would have my working directory in that single folder.
2. Run the command: `grep -r -i --include=*.vcxproj "YOUR_C/CPP_FILE" *`
3. The -r means recursively look in subdirectories, and the -i means ignore case (useful on windows, where you don't know what the file extension's case will be in the project file). grep should return that it has found something, assuming that file is contained in a project. There's usually a lot of stuff spit out by grep so piping that to a file may help you sift through it.